# Laravel giving Error on Broadcasting notifications, Pusher broadcast error

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, pusher

i did not changed any code in notifications in laravel, 
i just updated my versions and packages

now im getting the below error
       "{ "message": "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /home/forge/devapi.creatorshub.online/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 681", "exception": "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError", "file": "/home/forge/devapi.creatorshub.online/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php", "line": 135, "trace": [ { "file": "/home/forge/devapi.creatorshub.online/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php", "line": 681, "function": "parameterize", "class": "Illuminate\Database\Grammar", "type": "->" }, { "function": "Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/home/forge/devapi.creatorshub.online/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php", "line": 861, "function": "array_map" }"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case `notifications()` method has been overridden in my model. This method already exists inside trait `Notifiable`.